# Can't install package mod_ssl on Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

I need to install a application on a VPS Linux CentOS. But i'm having problems with mod_ssl:

When I run the command to install the app, it shows this warning:

```
Package 1:mod_ssl-2.4.6-97.el7.centos.x86_64 is obsoleted by ea-apache24-mod_ssl-2.4.46-6.12.1.cpanel.x86_64 which is already installed
```

And after:

```
Error: Package: filemaker_server-19.2.1-23.x86_64 (/filemaker_server-19.2.1-23.x86_64)
       Requires: mod_ssl
       Available: 1:mod_ssl-2.4.6-95.el7.centos.x86_64 (base)
           mod_ssl = 1:2.4.6-95.el7.centos
       Available: 1:mod_ssl-2.4.6-97.el7.centos.x86_64 (updates)
           mod_ssl = 1:2.4.6-97.el7.centos
```

If I try to install mod_ssl with yum install mod_ssl, it shows that:

```
No package mod_ssl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I am really stuck here. Someone can help me?

My repo list:

```
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Media.repo        CentOS-Vault.repo          dedi.repo          mysql-community.repo
CentOS-CR.repo         CentOS-SCLo-scl.repo     CentOS-x86_64-kernel.repo  EA4.repo           mysql-community-source.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-SCLo-scl-rh.repo  cPAddons.repo              epel.repo          UL_hostgator_br.repo
CentOS-fasttrack.repo  CentOS-Sources.repo      cpanel-plugins.repo        epel-testing.repo  ul.repo
```

When I yum search for mod_ssl:

```
mod_gnutls.x86_64 : GnuTLS module for the Apache HTTP server
```

Comment: Have you try to install w/o this dependence and try to run the service?

Comment: @RomeoNinov oh, it works haha!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: I enter it as answer. If it work for you you can mark it as correct answer and/or upvote (if you have enough reputation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case you can try to ignore this dependency (about `mode_ssl`) because you have in apache module for this functionality.

The commands you can use for example  are:

```
rpm -i --nodeps filemaker_server-19.2.1-23.x86_64.rpm
```

or

```
yum install --skip-broken filemaker_server-19.2.1-23.x86_64
```